# TSQL Determine Correct Day

Tags: sql-server, date

I found an issue yesterday with either my table design or a query that I pull data from and I need some guidance/suggestions on how to proceed and fix my problem.

My table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE 
[DT].[CountTotals](
    [Acct] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [TCount] [smallint] NOT NULL ,
    [TDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PostDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL ,
    [DayCount] [tinyint] NULL ,
    [AggCount] [smallint] NULL ,
    [AggNumber] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [IsReadyToArchive] [bit] NOT NULL 
)
```

I pull this data using the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [DT].[vwGetCountHistory]
AS

    SELECT     
        C.Acct, C.TCount, C.TDate, C.PostDate
        , C.DayCount, C.AggCount, C.AggNumber
    FROM DT.CountTotals C

    UNION

    SELECT     
        AC.Acct, AC.TCount, AC.TDate, AC.PostDate
        , AC.DayCount, AC.AggCount, AC.AggNumber
    FROM ARCHIVE.DTA.CountTotals AC
```

All of that works fine.  The table has about 300k records total records including about 5000 new records added to it each day, and the PostDate is the date the records are added. My issue is coming from the field DayCount - this field gets increased by 1 each day it is in the table, until the `PostDate is < GetDate()-90`.  My problem is in the following query:

```
SELECT     
        Acct
        , SUM(AggCount) AS SumofAggCount

    FROM DT.vwGetCountHistory
    WHERE (DayCount <= 5)
        AND 
        (
            PostDate >= @BusinessDate - 90
            AND PostDate <= @BusinessDate
        )
    GROUP BY Acct
    HAVING (SUM(AggCount) >= 4)
```

This query works wonderfully if I am searching for the current date because the DayCount would be correct.  But stupid me forgot that they can search for the data from previous days so my DayCount will have increased each day since the PostDate.

I am looking for suggestions about how to remedy this problem.  Is there a way to determine the correct daycount?

Comment: you have some process that increments DayCount?

Comment: Yes, I have a morning job that runs a stored proc to perform the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than store & manage DayCount, can you compute the number of days between @BusinessDate and PostDate in your query?

Comment: that is an idea but the business is adamant about storing and maintaining the DayCount. But if I can't figure out another solution, I might have to bring that up to them.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I am going to manually calculate the DayCount based on your suggestion.  I actually had not thought of that

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with @n8wrl that DayCount should most likely not be stored and should be calculated on the fly, but if that is not an option, then at the very least make it a Computed Column where it is a DATEDIFF between the PostDate and GETDATE() and get rid of that nightly process. Of course, that would still be, in effect, processing it on the fly but I don't think that the performance hit would be bad given the potential risk of the nightly job not running or running twice, etc.

Now, for the immediate need, can you just make the DayCount test more dynamic, such as:

```
WHERE (DayCount <= (5 + DATEDIFF(DAY, @BusinessDate, PostDate)))
```

Doing this we add 1 to the condition so that it would be DayCount <= 6 as yesterday's qualifying records now have a DayCount of 6.